# How to give Cypress test cases to execute for a non-technical person?

Tags: cypress

I don't want my users to install Node or command prompt to do operations, is there any way I can set up everything and give to client to run a specific scenario?

I found some Chrome extensions to record, is there any Chrome extension to do playback?

Comment: Why do they need to *execute* it? Could you run it in CI and provide the *results*, for example?

Answer (score 2):

The [Cypress Dashboard](https://www.cypress.io/dashboard/) seems like the best solution, since non technical users can run the tests and view the video recordings there.

Alternatively, you could set up Jenkins jobs that would run the tests on a server. In this way the users would be able to run the jobs manually via the Jenkins Dashboard, then view the results in the Console Output for the build, within the build history.